# Javaflow Continuation: Trying to Save Static variable

Tags: continuations, static-variables, checkpoint

I had been trying to create some check-pointing solutions using [Javaflow](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/javaflow/) . It works well with all the local variable. But it is unable to save the static variable instance. I am trying to do something like this:

foo( ){

```
  //Doing Something

  //Writing the static variable value, suppose 
  MyClass.StaticValue=10;

  Continuation.suspend( );  //Checkpoint P created

  //Do Something

  //Update the static value, suppose
  MyClass.StaticValue=11;

  return;
```

}

Now when i try to restore back from checkPoint P, I expect to read the StaticValue as 10, but it is 11. I have two questions regarding it:

1. Is it a expected behavior from Javaflow or I am missing something while using Javaflow?
2. Is there a smart way to store these static variable other than using some versioning and storing all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer:
1. Javaflow don't support static variables check-pointing.
2. Only versioning looks like a direction.

Comment: JavaFlow only capture/restore loacal variables and method arguments. Neither instance nor static class members are captured/restored.